# occurrence of string

Tags: php, strstr

i know you can find the first and last occurrence in a string using `strstr()` and `strchr` but how do i find the second occurrence, and the third occurrence of needle inside haystack? im using this to find the last occurrence of needle and the first occurrence of another needle and their position, then return the string that is in between each. thank you.

Comment: +1 - I really wish that they had a str*n*pos function or something for this, to find the nth occurrence.  You pretty much have to fake it using the other string functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strpos()` and update the `offset` value to be after whatever you just matched.

Answer (score 1):

You must find by strstr(), get result and start finding from result for time when strstr dont find nothing new.

You can use for it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 0):

For the last occurrence, use [`strrpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php).

```
$lastPos = strrpos($haystack, $needle);
```

It takes an optional offset argument too.